# How can I get a value that's inside parentheses in a string in Python?

Tags: python

I've got something like this:

```
a = '2(3.4)'
b = '12(3.5)'
```

I only want the value inside the brackets. I used regex, and it worked, but my teacher won't allow it. How can I do this?

Comment: How robust should the solution be?

Comment: @Matt Fenwick's question is critical. What is the range of inputs your code is reasonably expected to deal with?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
>>> a = '2(3.4)'
>>> a[a.index("(") + 1:a.rindex(")")]
'3.4'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> a, b = '2(3.4)', '12(3.5)'
>>> def extract(string, start='(', stop=')'):
        return string[string.index(start)+1:string.index(stop)]

>>> extract(a), extract(b)
('3.4', '3.5')
>>>
```