# How can I do this better? With Regex?

Tags: python, regex

friends. 
I have this code in my python application:

```
if '(' in obj.value or ')' in obj.value:
    city, country = obj.value.upper()[:-1].split('(')
    found = city.strip() == self.customer.city.upper() and country == self.customer.country.upper()
else:
    city = obj.value.upper()
    found = city.strip() == self.customer.city.upper()
```

A text string that can be with the following possible values​​:

> 'New York' or 'New York (NY)'

But the problem is that the code below does not guarantee a possible error, for example, be missing one of the brackets. Eg

> 'New York NY)'

How can I improve and protect this little snippet?
There is a formula in Regex, for example?
(I know some regex)

Comment: `continue` is a reserved word in Python, btw; you cannot use it as the name of a variable.

Comment: Thanks @ErikAllik. I Edited my example. Surely, I dont use this word. :)

Comment: To clarify - you want _either_ no parentheses, or _two_: an opening and a closing one, with the opening coming before the closing. Do you want just two capital letters between these parentheses? The clearer your requirements, the better the answer you get...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040795/how-can-i-get-a-value-thats-inside-parentheses-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: Note also potential typo - `contry` vs `country`...

Comment: @Floris, I always need to feed the variable City. The variable Country, I feed if there is a setting between parentheses.

Comment: You claim you edited the example but `continue` is still there.

Comment: What do you want to do with the string `New York NY)`?

Comment: Also you should remove the `upper()` stuff from the question, because it is not relevant and just confuses the issue.

Comment: Finally, please fix the question title to relate to the question.  You really should read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) before asking more questions.

Comment: Just a guess that it is required to get the city name and its abbreviated name.
Like: New York (NY) -> 'New York', 'NY'
Los Angeles (LA) -> 'Los Angeles', 'LA'

Comment: @gsmaker - I suspect that the bit in parentheses is the state (so it would be `Los Angeles (CA)` ). Or, as the code would have it, the `contry`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
m = re.match('(.+) \((.+)\)', obj.value)
if m:
    city, country = m.groups()
else:
    city, country = obj.value, None
```

Comment: `city, country = obj.value, None` would be a bit more correct, semantically.